# Points on the opposing side of a breakline

Tags: dem, line, geometry, breaklines, computational-geometry

If you have a breakline or even a single line segment within a DEM, how can you tell if two points lie on the opposing side of that breakline or line segment? From a computational geometry standpoint is the cross product of two lines the only alternative? Additionally, how would you scale this issue when you have thousands/millions of points and breaklines/segments? I am trying to preserve breaklines by restricting smoothing across them.

Comment: I think your question will attract answers if you enhance it with real images of your actual data, explain your data types. A DEM is a raster so how can you have a "single line segment within" it? That's a vector data type! Shows us a scenario of when you have lots of data.